# Gitlab: pre-fill issue form through hyperlink

Tags: gitlab

On GitHub it is possible to easily pre-fill the form for a new issue with URL params like this:

https://github.com/docToolchain/docToolchain/issues/new?title=a+title&body=a+test+body%0Awith+two+lines

Is there also such a feature for gitlab?

I couldn't find this in the docs or through google...

Comment: Do you mean GitHub or GitLab?

Comment: @ThomasKainrad The working example link if for GitHub but I am looking for a solution for GitLab

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
?issue[title]=This+goes+to+the+title&issue[description]=and+this+will%0Aprefill+the+body
```

Example:

[https://gitlab.com/ralf-d-mueller/GradlePluginWorkshop/issues/new?issue[title]=This+goes+to+the+title&issue[description]=and+this+will%0Aprefill+the+body](https://gitlab.com/ralf-d-mueller/GradlePluginWorkshop/issues/new?issue%5Btitle%5D=This+goes+to+the+title&issue%5Bdescription%5D=and+this+will%0Aprefill+the+body)

And here is the reference to the docs:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#using-a-url-with-prefilled-values

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about pre-filling, but you can preselect a [description template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html) with the `issuable_template` query parameter.

Example which pre-selects the "Doc Review" template:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/new?issuable_template=Doc%20Review

Comment: that is already quite good. But I want to pre-fill some more information - the url which corresponds to the issue.